# Duplicate DOM node jQuery (not reference)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clone

I am developing a dynamic form, and I need to duplicate a node and insert it into another DOM position.

My problem is that when I first copy the node (which contains empty inputs), I fill it with data, and I copy it again, it is copied with all the data.

I would like to duplicate the variable containing the empty DOM node and not refer to it.

It's possible?

```
var emptySegment = $( '#segment' ).clone();

$(document ).on('click', '#add', function(){
    var emptySgmt = emptySegment; // Duplicate emptySegment. 
    emptySgmt.insertAfter( '.lastSegment' );
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you clone the element you need to reset the `input` (or any other elements) back to the state you require. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
    cloneSegment().insertAfter('.lastSegment');
});

function cloneSegment() {
    return $('#segment').clone().find('input').val('').end();
}
```

Note this example simply resets the `value` of all `input` elements within the segment. You can put your own logic in there to meet whatever your specific requirements are.

Comment: Or perhaps `.val(function() { return this.defaultValue; }).end();` in order to respect the default it was given in the markup originally.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wanted to avoid doing that. I have many inputs on the node that is being cloned. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JSGarcia: It's Rory's answer. But I'm unclear on what it is you want to avoid, and why...? (If it's what's in my comment above, just for the avoidance of doubt, that's literal code. The `defaultValue` property of an `input` reflects the `value` attribute, which is the *default* value of the input, not its current value. And even if you had several thousand `input` elements in the segment, it wouldn't take any significant time to run.)

Comment: @JSGarcia not sure why you'd want to avoid what TJ mentioned? As I mentioned in the answer, you can incorporate any logic you need after the `clone()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
var emptySegment = $( '#segment' ).clone(); // Provided this is empty

  $(document ).on('click', '#add', function(){
  var emptySgmt = emptySegment.clone(); // clone it again to get prisitine copy each time
  emptySgmt.insertAfter( '.lastSegment' );
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it isn't clone of a clone but clone of a desired object, which is cloned only once and serve as a matrix.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I think what he/she is doing here is making the first clone up-front, before the user does anything to set values. Then later, cloning the clone avoids using the values that the user set, because they weren't set on the initial clone.